# Pretty-print expression recursively

Tags: sml

```
infix v;
infix &;
datatype s = P | Q | S
         | ~ of s
         | v of s * s
         | & of s * s;
```

I made a function (s -> unit) to print type s as string

```
fun printS(P) = print "P"
  | printS(Q) = print "Q"
  | printS(P & Q) = print "P & Q";
```

My Question is how can I print s recursively if  I have more complex s such as 
P v ~ Q & P.

Answer (score 3):

You can pretty-print an expression recursively by pattern-matching the sub-trees as variables and then refer to those sub-trees. In your example, you are only matching `P & Q` which is exactly one tree.

```
fun printS P = print "P"
  | printS Q = print "Q"
  | printS S = print "S"
  | printS (p & q) = (print or printS ...; print or printS ...; ...)
```

By not referring to actual `P` and `Q`, but instead variables `p` and `q`, these could be any sub-expression. Since your function returns *unit*, you'd want to print multiple times. Except, perhaps, some of the things you want to print are recursive datatypes, so you could use your specialized `printS` instead.

I would probably convert this to a string and print the string once:

```
fun toString P = "P"
  | toString Q = "Q"
  | toString S = "S"
  | toString (p & q) = "(" ^ toString p ^ " & " ^ toString q ^ ")"
  | toString ... = ...
```

and then print it:

```
fun printS s = print (toString s)
```

The real challenge comes at printing the minimal amount of parentheses:

```
printS ((P v Q) & (Q v P))
```

should preferrably not print `P v Q & Q v P`, since those aren't the same expressions.